# Comparing two dates in different month return nothing in PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a code that looks like this:

```
while ($DateNow <= $DateFinish) {
    echo "<td>".$DateNow." | ".$DateFinish."</td>";
    $DateNow = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("next day, ".$Datenow));  
}
```

This code is inside a table so it will make a new cell for every day in a week.
`$DateNow` start in this week monday, `$DateFinish` in Saturday. So it will make 6 new <td>.

It works well but the problem occur when the compared date is in different month, like for example Monday 29 Aug with Saturday 3 Sept, it returns nothing. I tried with every possible weeks that has 2 months in it, nothing show up. But when still in 1 month, it shows up.

Any thoughts about this?

Comment: `01-02-2016` is lexically smaller than `31-01-2016`. You need to compare dates in the `Y-m-d` format if you want to loop like this.

Comment: What are these values for `$DateNow` and `$DateFinish`? Are they strings?

Comment: for now, it use d-m-Y format and let say the date are date type.

Comment: @DavidDalvin If you are using the [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function then your dates are being stored as strings. You are comparing them lexicographically.

Comment: @DavidDalvin Always format dates with the largest unit of time first (year, month, date, hour, minute, second...) if you want to compare them. This is why timestamps in a SQL database, for example, are in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you order a set of dates in `d-m-Y` format lexicographically (alphabetically), you do not get the ordering you would expect.

For instance

```
30-01-2016
31-01-2016
01-02-2016
02-02-2016
28-02-2016
29-02-2016
01-03-2016
02-03-2016
```

becomes

```
01-02-2016
01-03-2016
02-02-2016
02-03-2016
28-02-2016
29-02-2016
30-01-2016
31-01-2016
```

after sorting.

To get a more sensible ordering when comparing in this way, you need to change the date format into something more conducive to natural ordering (such as `Y-m-d`).